# Probability of making a given pair

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I found this question in a website while preparing for an interview.

Q. 5 women and 5 men are to be married. Out of 5 men 3 are above age 30. Out of 10 women 4 women are above age 30. What is the probability that everyone gets married and all 3 men above age 30 get married to women above age 30?

Select your answer from below:

1.(9*64)/(25*16*9*4*1)

2.(864)/(25*16*9*4*1)

3.(6*64)/(25*16*9*4*1)

4.(7*64)/(25*16*9*4*1)

Now, my approach was to first calculate the number of ways of obtaining the said outcome. So, first we'd choose 3 women out of 4 to be married to 3 men. That would give $\binom{4}{3}$ and arrange them in $3!$ ways. Then we'll choose 2 women out of 7 and arrange then in $2!$ ways. Now total no of outcomes should be $\binom{10}{5} × 5!$. Thus probability comes out to be $1/30$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Men are only allowed to marry women?

Comment: I get the same answer you do.

Comment: @Matthew yeah I believe so. I tried this approach but still didn't get an answer to even remotely match the options.